# How do you name your json methods?

Tags: python, objective-c, json

I work with a bit of `json` in my code. I work with it in both `Objective-C` and `python` (3 of course!). Someday, I'll probably be forced to work with it in `java`. All of these platforms have libraries for parsing `json` strings into native objects, usually dictionaries with stuff in them.

So every time I write a method/function that either produces or consumes json data, I'm always torn. Because sometimes, they consume or produce it in string form, and sometimes they do it in the higher level form.

For example, let's say I have a `Script` object that reifies some scheduling, and I can turn it into `json` for easy http transmission or mongo-ification, or whatever. And so I make two methods:

```
class Script(object):
    def toJson(self):
        ...
    def fromJson(self, json):
        ...
```

While these methods communicate that the `Script` object can populate itself or represent itself via `json`, it's totally unclear which form. Is the `json` variable there a `dict` or or a string?

So I'm wondering if others have evolved naming conventions that help clarify this?

Comment: I'm not sure how SO feels about questions like this -- but I find THESE are the most useful questions/threads of discussion. I really enjoy "best practice" discussions. Thanks for the Q.

Comment: I would expect `json` to be a string in any case. Otherwise `def from_dict(d)` would make more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I do a bit of pymongo as well, where it's common to refer to these structured dictionaries as *docs*, I began using that term (after discussing this question with a number of peers elsewhere). So I have methods/functions that look like:

```
def toDoc(self):
    ...
```

and

```
- (void) fromDoc: (NSDictionary*) doc {
    ...
}
```

Then, if I want to paper over those with json variants which do the to/from string encoding, I name this with `JSON`.

I realized in the end, that in JavaScript itself, this doesn't come up, because it's just an object already. But with languages like `Python` and `ObjectiveC` we tend to use intermediary literal objects such as dictionaries and lists as we step between our domain objects and JSON. What I really needed was some word that meant "JavaScriptishObjectStructure" or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

I run into a similar issue (althought in my case it's xml). It may not be elegant, but I have a tendency to use the type name when returning that type, and append 'str' when returning a stringified version of the type. Eg:

```
class Script:
    def tojson(self):
        ...
    def tojsonstr(self):
        ...
    def fromjson(self, json):
        ...
    def fromjsonstr(self, jsonstr):
        ...
```

I've experimented w/ adding underscores, but in the long run, this just creates cumbersome identifiers (and my fingers get twisted typing longer strings).

I suppose you could get clever, and test the passed object for isinstance (at least in the case of fromX(), Eg:

```
def fromjson(self, json):
    if isinstance(json, basestring):
        # assume str
    else:
        # assume json object
    ...
```

Comment: Yeah, I considered the "clever" type check thing. But that just seems wrong to me. Better to be explicit. And you can't be symmetric about it either. You can only play that card on the input side, not the output side. Unless you're going to make ALL of your json handling points do the same either string or dict trick.

Comment: Actually, if you went with fromjson() doing the insinstance() check, I'd probably change my tojson() to ALWAYS return json objects, and require the caller to do tostring(). It doesn't seem unreasonable to require the caller to write JSONEncoder().encode(s.tojson()) to get a string